# Wordpress plugin to create list of banners with copy/paste code

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need a plugin to help me automate the creation of a banner page. Here's the existing page: http://stopsb249.org/get-banners-for-your-website/  and it should be immediately obvious to everyone what I need :)

Basically, I want to be able to add a banner image to the plugin, and have it generate the page based on the banners in the database.

So, upload a 125x125 Square? Show that on the page with a textarea below it with the html needed to add it to YOUR website.

I don't really want to code it myself, so I'm hoping someone knows if there's a plugin that exists that will actually do this already.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it yourself, I tend to stay away from plugins and create things myself because I like to have full functionality to my blogs. You could create a new page and use a page template. Then if you wanted to be easy you could upload these photos to flickr and then use some PHP to get the photo, write the HTML you want and then use PHP for the image source and link.

Or you can get technical and create a metabox that will allow you to upload photos and it will display for you.

To answer your question, no, I do not know of any but I am sure there may be at least one out there, the chance that you'll find one for something your looking for is slim. Sorry.